# Toastr notification running a blank notification on pageload

Tags: javascript, toastr

Im catching the Html.ValidationSummary in a toastr notification which works fine, Issue i have is that it keeps showing a blank error toastr notification on page load.

Ive removed the onload class from my body tag in the page layout, but no luck.

Source,

```
        var message = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(((@Html.ValidationSummary()==null)?"":@Html.ValidationSummary().ToHtmlString())));
if (message.length > 0) {
    toastr.error(message);
    }
```

I have already tried using `toastr.remove();`but had no luck.

Comment: care to share a fiddle of the code?

Comment: Will do, give me 5 minutes.